# Getting file too large error while using catopen() function

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm getting errno 27[EFBIG]: file too large while opening catalogue with catopen() function in cygwin-32bit version. How to resolve it?
Note: File size is 44kb.

Trying to open .cat file but catopen() returns file too large [EFBIG] error.

this is the code snippet I was working with:

```
#define FILENAME    TEMP.CAT

   buffer = catopen(FILENAME, 0);
        if (buffer != (nl_catd) - 1)
         {
            printf("File open successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("errno: %d\n", errno);
        }
```

while debugging I've found that st.st_size is 0 and I'm not sure about the value of SIZE_T_MAX parameter i think it may be have garbage value .so that's why if condition getting success and returning errno 27(EFBIG).
Coding snippet where if condition getting succeed:

```
 if (st.st_size > SIZE_T_MAX) {
        _close(fd);
        SAVEFAIL(name, lang, EFBIG);
        NLRETERR(EFBIG);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see in your question any code which would use `catopen`...

Comment: I meet the same problem, it always return EFBIG when using the catopen, even the cat file is less then 1K on the Cygwin 32 bit 3.3.6

Comment: Actually when I moved to Cygwin 64 bit, I didn't face this issue. I guess Cygwin 32 bit is deprecated that's why it was giving this issue.